# Древовидная структура БД SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

Подскажите, покажите пример, как создавать таблицы древовидных структур, и как выполнять запрос к ним на добавление данных.

Допустим у нас есть таблица пользователей Table_Name_user:

```
 |Table_Name_user|
 |-------|
 |user_id|
 |-------|
 |      0|
 |-------|
 |      1|
 |-------|
 |      2|
 |-------|
 |..и.т.д|
```

если мы находим какого-то пользователя по user_id, допустим "2", то мы должны узнать сколько друзей он себе добавил. Как это сделать с помощью древовидной структуры БД?

Должно получиться что у каждого user_id, есть как бы своя таблица, в которой он может добавлять или удалять друзей. **ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ**: своя таблица, это не значит отдельная таблица в базе, а значит какая-то подтаблица которая будет храниться в ячейке отдельного юзера.

**table_friend** - **уникальная таблица**, которая есть у каждого user_id. table_friend - не находятся отдельно в базе, они прикреплены к каждой ячейки user_id.

```
|Table_Name_user|
     |-------|
     |user_id|
     |-------|
     |      0|----------|table_friend|(это не отдельная таблица в базе)
     |-------|
     |      1|----------|table_friend|(это не отдельная таблица в базе)
     |-------|
     |      2|----------|table_friend|(это не отдельная таблица в базе)
     |-------|
     |..и.т.д|
```

Comment: Друзья тоже пользователи?

Comment: Друзья тоже могут быть пользователями.

Comment: @semiromid С вашим новым комментарием про _хранение в ячейке_ таблица нарушает 1НФ и запрос вида "А кто добавил в друзья меня" пойдет полным сканированием таблицы. Так просто никто в реляционных БД не делает

Comment: Я отредактировал свой вопрос, прочтите пожалуйста его еще раз.

Comment: @semiromid На что я уже с упреждением написал, что ваша идея нарушает 1НФ (1 нормальная форма, в гугле находится прямо так). Ну в Oracle есть например nested table, только ими пользоваться тяжело

Comment: @semiromid Могут быть пользователями, а могу и не быть пользователями? Так? Отдельную таблицу можно сделать (и то не всегда) когда пользователь является пользователем БД. В MSSQL это особо хорошо сделано (из всех известных мне БД). Но это бывает в самых отсталых или очень специальных программах. Ещё можно порекомендовать поле типа BLOB|TEXT|XML в таблице Users. Но тогда друзья не могут быть пользователями (точнее с оооочень большим трудом)

Comment: banme То есть, друзья тоже пользователи? Друзьями могут быть только пользователи.

Comment: @semiromid Если все пользователи, то см ответы Mike, i-one. Хотя иллюстраций у них нет, но всё верно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда друзья не пользователи. (Когда пользователи рисовать больше в лом)
Таблицы пользователей и друзей связываются по некоторому ключевому полю. Естественно взять в качестве ключа связи поле Id из таблицы Users.

```
    Users                  Frends
+-------------+       +-------------+
| Id          |<--+   | Id          |
| Name        |   +-<<| User_Id     |
| ...         |       | Name        |
|             |       | ...         |
```

Извлечь всех друзей пользователя номер N:
`SELECT * FROM FRENDS WHERE User_Id = N`

Извлечь пользователей вместе с их друзьями:
`SELECT * FFOM USERS U LEFT JOIN FRENDS F ON F.User_Id = U.Id`

Добавить друга пользователю номер N:
`INSERT INTO FRENDS (User_Id, ...) VALUES (N, ...)`

Удалить друзей:
`DELETE FROM FRENDS WHERE User_Id = N`

И где вы тут дерево нашли. Так ветка одна.

В таблице FRENDS переписаны друзья всех всех пользователей. Но у каждой записи есть поле (User_Id), которое ссылается на пользователя, чей это друг.
В запросы вставляются условия на это поле, чтобы отделить нужных друзей от чужих. Таким нехитрым способом получается как бы своя таблица друзей на пользователя.
Освойте этот простой приём. Все более сложные схемы опираются на него.

```
  Users
  Id   Name
+----+------------------+
|  1 | Серёжа           |
|  2 | Маша             |
...

  Frends
  Id   User_Id   Name      - по User_Id ясно
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 |    1    | Андрюша | - друг Серёжи
|  2 |    1    | Марина  | - подружка Серёжи
|  3 |    2    | Оксана  | - подружка Маши
...
```

Comment: а как без рекурсивного запроса извлечь друзей и их друзей и друзей-друзей и так далее, т.е. все поддерево?

Comment: @Stack Как можете заметить, моя структура не предполагает никаких деревьев друзей. Только самые азы связи двух таблиц. Более сложные структуры придумать и  без меня умников хватает:)

Comment: Frends таблица - будет общая для всех, но я имею в виду другое.  Должно получится что у каждого user_id, есть как бы своя таблица, в которой он может добавлять или удалять друзей. ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ: своя таблица, это не значит отдельная таблица в базе, а значит какая-то подтаблица которая будет храниться в ячейки отдельного юзера.

Comment: @Stack Для деревьев, херархических структур, для облегчения работы с ними придумали CTE рекурсивные. Common Table Expression. Многие БД поддерживают. некоторые навереное еще нет.

Comment: @semiromid Так всё делается через общие таблицы, но с фильтрацией в запросах по ключевому полю. Ничего нового пока не изобрели и не собираются. Это задача программиста составить правильные запросы

Comment: @banme про CTE - знаю. в моем ответе есть. просто в T-SQL еще есть hierarchyId, думал, что и в других БД что-то подобное реализовано.

Comment: Я отредактировал свой вопрос, прочтите пожалуйста его еще раз для полного понимания и уверенности.

Answer (score 2):

Делается *одна* таблица для обеспечения связи типа "многие-ко-многим", такого вида

```
create table friends( user_id, friend_id );
```

Где `user_id` - id пользователя который добавил себе друга, `friend_id` id друга - такого же пользователя

Добавлять друзей элементарно, просто заносим в эту таблицу запись с соответствующими id.

Получить кол-во прямых друзей

```
select count(1) from friends where user_id=NN
```

Количество пользователей добавивших в друзья конкретного пользователя NN:

```
select count(1) from friends where friend_id=NN
```

Получение полного списка друзей с именами (они же есть в таблице пользователей) пользователя NN:

```
select F.friend_id, U.name
  from friends F join users U on (U.user_id=F.friend_id)
 where F.user_id=NN
```

А вот работать с такой таблицей именно как с древовидной, что бы одним запросом получить всех друзей друзей и т.д. углубляясь в дерево на mysql и sqllite очень тяжело, потому как их диалект SQL не поддерживает `connect by`. Можете в интернете поискать по фразе, например `mysql connect by` можно найти как это обходить, но обычно это индивидуальные решения. Тем более в вашем случае пользователь с `ID 1` может добавить друга `ID 2`, а второй добавит в друзья первого. т.е. в базе будут 2 записи `(1,2)` и `(2,1)`. И в таком случае алгоритм строящий дерево должен уметь обрубать ветви, что бы не зациклится на таких ссылках.

Comment: create table friends( user_id, friend_id );  - Если мы для каждого юзера будет создавать собственную таблицу, то будет очень много таблиц в базе. Не получиться сделать так что бы у каждого юзера как бы была своя подтаблица, которая каким то образом размещалась в главной таблице( список юзеров)?

Comment: @semiromid Вы не поняли, мы делаем всего 1 таблицу. Если бы таблиц мы делали много, то внутри только один id друга понадобился.

Comment: Получается что при добавлении двух друзей одного и тогоже user_id, запись в ячейки user_id, продублируется, и таблица будет на одну строку больше? Если мы добавим 10 друзей, одного и того же user_id, то таблица будет на 10 строк больше? А нельзя ли сделать что бы в каждой строке ures_id, как бы была внутреннея таблица со списком друзей?

Comment: _"что бы одним запросом получить всех друзей друзей и т.д."_ -- в T-SQL есть поддержка рекурсивных CTE -- [тут](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: @semiromid Да, совершенно верно. Будет много записей. Но это совершенно не страшно, с такой структурой очень легко работать. И собственно в реляционных БД все хранят именно в таком виде. Если нужен другой вид - нужны noSQL базы, но там свои проблемы

Comment: Я отредактировал свой вопрос, прочтите пожалуйста его еще раз для полного понимания и уверенности.

Answer (score 2):

Похоже вам нужна не древовидная структура, а обычное отношение многие ко многим.

Например, таблица пользователей:

```
create table users
(
    user_id int primary key
)
```

Друзья пользователя:

```
create table user_friends
(
    user_id int,
    friend_id int,
    primary key (user_id, friend_id),
    foreign key (user_id) references users (user_id),
    foreign key (friend_id) references users (user_id)
)
```

Добавим пользователей:

```
insert into users (user_id) values (1)
insert into users (user_id) values (2)
insert into users (user_id) values (3)
```

Пользователь 1 зафрендил пользователей 2 и 3:

```
insert into user_friends (user_id, friend_id) values (1, 2)
insert into user_friends (user_id, friend_id) values (1, 3)
```

Сколько друзей у пользователя 1:

```
select count(friend_id)
from user_friends
where user_id = 1
```

Древовидная структура обычно используется, когда есть иерархия или подчинение (напр. Директорат -> Замы -> Подчиненные), и в этом случае таблица сама на себя должна ссылаться.

Comment: Я отредактировал свой вопрос, прочтите пожалуйста его еще раз для полного понимания и уверенности.

Answer (score 1):

> table_friend - не находятся отдельно в базе, они прикреплены к каждой ячейки user_id.

В такой ситуации в SQL Server можно использовать поле xml.

```
create table Users (id int, friends xml)
insert Users (id, friends) values (12345,  
                N'<best-friends>
                    <user id='111' />
                    <user id='222' />
                    <user id='333' />
                  </best-friends>')
```

для выборки всех best-friends/user/@id пишем примерно такой запрос:

```
select x.value('@id', 'nvarchar(100)') from Users 
  CROSS APPLY types.nodes('//best-friend/user') t(x)
```

Comment: а если нету SQL Server, как быть тогда?

Comment: Тогда любой поле, которое может хранить text. xml - это текст. xml поле облегчает работу с ним в запросах. А так самому разбирать. И в любом случае обеспечивать синхронизацию id из xml с id из users придётся вручную, что очень непросто. И каждый скажет, что так делать нельзя

Comment: В таком случае он ничем не будет отличаться от массива данных которые поместить в ячейку каждого юзера. Верно? Если я такую таблицу создам: create table Users (id int, friends varchar) то в friends, будем размещать массивы в формате JSON.

Comment: @semiromid _"если нету SQL Server, как быть тогда?"_ без встроенной поддержки xml, использовать text - неэффективно, т.к. придется извлекать весь text целиком, преобразовывать его в xml и т.д.
в такой ситуации проще всего создать отдельную таблицу и хранить в ней отношения.

Answer (score 0):

> как создавать таблицы древовидных структур, и как выполнять запрос к ним на добавление данных.

В таблицу надо добавить поле, например, ParentId. Примерно так:

```
create table Users (Id int, ParentId int, Name nvarchar(100))
insert Users (Id, ParentId, Name) values (0, NULL, 'u1'), (1, 0, 'u2')
```

> мы должны узнать сколько друзей он себе добавил. Как это сделать с помощью древовидной структуры БД?

Если считать, что "твой друг - это мой друг", то в такой ситуации древовидная структура не подходит. Можно создать **таблицу отношений**, например, так:

```
create table Relations (UserId1 int, UserId2 int, Type int, Created datetime);
```

Такая таблица позволяет хранить любые связи между людьми.
Если надо выбрать всех потомков (т.е. детей и их детей и т.д.), то в T-SQL используются CTE with recursion -- [рекурсивные запросы](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: То есть, получается что будет одна таблица в которой можно добавить или удалить друга  для всех user_id ? Не получиться сделать так что бы у каждого юзера как бы была своя подтаблица, которая каким то образом размещалась в главной таблице( список юзеров)?

Comment: Parent - это же вроде батя пользователя?

Comment: @semiromid отношения между людьми бывают разными. лучше  создать отдельную таблицу. и для выборки подтаблицы использовать CTE.

Comment: Я отредактировал свой вопрос, прочтите пожалуйста его еще раз для полного понимания и уверенности.